# Where are AWS SQS message built-in message attributes documented?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm sending messages to AWS SQS with the Node.js SDK. I cannot find the documentation that lists the various built-in attributes that can be specified in a message. The example in the documentation specifies an attribute called "DelaySeconds", but I don't see where that is documented anywhere??

Presumably that instructs the SDK to wait n seconds before sending the message? I'm trying to get the full list of Attributes I'm allowed to specify in a message. Note: I'm not referring to the MessageAttributes where I can specify my own message attributes, I'm referring to attributes that AWS looks at, such as MessageBody, QueueURL, DelaySeconds, etc.

Here is link to documentation I'm looking at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html

Full Example code here:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create an SQS service object
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});

var params = {
  DelaySeconds: 10,     <--- where is this documented?
  MessageAttributes: {
    "Title": {
      DataType: "String",
      StringValue: "The Whistler"
    },
    "Author": {
      DataType: "String",
      StringValue: "John Grisham"
    },
    "WeeksOn": {
      DataType: "Number",
      StringValue: "6"
    }
  },
  MessageBody: "Information about current NY Times fiction bestseller for week of 12/11/2016.",
  // MessageDeduplicationId: "TheWhistler",  // Required for FIFO queues
  // MessageId: "Group1",  // Required for FIFO queues
  QueueUrl: "SQS_QUEUE_URL"
};

sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
  }
});
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property

Answer (score 0):

I found documentation here, was linked from page, just didnt see it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property